# Mounting Ethernet wall-plate in a solid wall

Tags: walls

I have an Ethernet cable running through a small hole in a solid concrete block wall. I want to cover the hole with [a plate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074Q6LW8V):
[image]

[image]

Do I need a mount/bracket or can I just screw in the plate? A bracket will require a much large hole.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of the actual cable and hole would be helpful; please edit it into your question.

Comment: @jsotola I could but I only want to if it's necessary.

Comment: you could glue the plate to the wall .... the hole in the wall would have to be enlarged slightly to hold the connector

Comment: @jsotola It's a marble floor. Glue or screws? Which would work better?

Comment: you said that the wall is concrete ..... if you feel like drilling concrete, then use screws, otherwise use glue or double-sided foam tape, like the tape for 3M wall hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Ethernet cables no box is needed since the wall is solid block a set of low voltage wings won't work. You may need to make the hole slightly larger so the plate will sit flush with the wall when you attach it but it would be legal.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing easier.  Install any sort of electrical 1-gang junction box on the surface of the wall.  Remove a knockout from the back of the box, and line it up so the wire comes through the middle of it.

The cover plate you linked is designed to fit to a 1-gang box.

I would go for either a $1 handy-box, or a Wiremold surface conduit box, depending on the aesthetic you want.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a picture of the hole. What would happen if I just screw in the plate directly into the wall. The plate is purely for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: If it fits. This is low voltage, so that's legit.

Comment: Cool, so I'll try just the plate first to see how it fits (should just about) or make the hole a little bigger.

Comment: @Summingdate -- it's legal, but not a good idea because the screws don't hold well in drywall

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's not a drywall. It's a concrete-block wall.

Comment: Ah, then well, I think that you should be able to use appropriate fasteners to make the plate hold, then.

Answer (score 1):

#### Surface Mount Box

Get a surface mount box. As with a wall plate, make sure it is up to the spec. you need (e.g., Cat 5e or Cat 6). Plenty available at a big box or [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0054RSP8I).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a masonry bit just use any junky bit and drill the two small holes a little bit bigger than your screws. Put a toothpick in the holes followed by the screws. Done!